# Slow Lucene.Net search performance

Tags: performance, lucene.net

Facing slow search performance using Lucene.Net (+ NHibernate.Search but that doesn't matter).

Luke toolbox overview:

- Number of fields: 33
- Number of documents: 5607
- Number of terms: 101377
- Has deletions? / Optimized?: Yes (97478) / No

Index directory is ~200Mb large.

Query (using org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer)

> Title:lapsa~0.5 Abstract:lapsa~0.5 Content:lapsa~0.5 Location:lapsa~0.5 Author:lapsa~0.5

takes ~60000ms in average.

---

I suspect I'm missing something important. Any ideas what's wrong? Can't be that this is normal.

---

Tried to 'check' and 'fix' them. Had to tick `Don't open IndexReader (when opening corrupted index)`, otherwise `Check index tool` doesn't want to show up.

Results of checking:

> BAD: missingSegments

Diagnostic output:

> ERROR: could not read any segments file in directory
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory@D:\Temp\Index: files:
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:655)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:538)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:306)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:340)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:319)
>       at org.getopt.luke.Luke$6.run(Unknown Source)

Tried to press `Fix Index`. Got this:

> ERROR during Fix Index:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.fixIndex(CheckIndex.java:781)
>       at org.getopt.luke.Luke$7.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you try optimizing? It looks like you've got a *lot* of pending deletions...

Comment: @codeka when i press `luke->tools->optimize index`, it says `Failed: no index, or index is closed. Reopen it." and reopening doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you've got a corrupted index. Are there *any* files in your D:\Temp\Index folder? I assume there must be or searching wouldn't work at all... What version of Lucene.Net are you using? Earlier versions used to corrupt the index for me at the drop of a hat, but the later versions seem to be much better in that respect.

If you can't figure it out, you might just have to rebuild the index from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In Luke go to the Tools menu and select check index tool. See if your index is corrupted or has other issues.

Comment: It says there are missing segments. Wtf?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-optimize.html) one helped me. Switched on automatic optimization.